# Can't call method after casting

Tags: actionscript-3, casting

I'm trying to figure out why `ActionScript` won't let me call methods on an Object after casting it.

I have a set of objects in an `Array`, all of which extend my `ActionBase` class.  I want to go through all of them and call their step() and done() methods.

However, when I try to do so, the compiler gives me an error:

> Error: Call to a possibly undefined method

If I simply create an `ActionBase` Object directly and call these methods on it, it works fine. So I suspect there's something about the casting that `ActionScript` doesn't like.

This is the code:

```
private var actionQueue:Array = new Array();
...

var action:ActionBase;

for (var i:int = 0; i < actionQueue.length; ++i)
{
    action = actionQueue[i] as ActionBase;

    if (action != null && action is ActionBase)
    {

        action.step();

        if ( action.done() )
        {

            newQueue.push(action);
        }

    }
}
```

actionQueue is being appended to by having it's push() method called with objects which extends ActionBase.  I'm also using FlashDevelop as my IDE.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

My ActionBase class:

```
public class ActionBase 
{
    public function ActionBase() 
    {

    }

    public function done():Boolean
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function step():void
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you hide parts of the error, post the entire error.

Comment: The code looks correct and works in isolation. The compile-error seems to indicate that it recognizes `ActionBase` but does not recognize the methods of `ActionBase`. Do you have more than one `ActionBase` class, or more than one `action` variable? What happens when you use ["go to definition"](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Shortcuts)?

Answer (score 0):

It may be as easy as changing the method from private to public. (didn't try it myself though and sorry can't write comments due to reputation level.)

Comment: All the methods on my ActionBase are public.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code looks fine, what does your ActionBase class and Array (actionQueue) assignment look like?

i.e.

```
actionQueue[actionQueue.length] = new ActionBase();
```

Cut/Paste Example:

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Main extends Sprite {
    private var actionQueue:Array = new Array();
    public function Main() {
        var action:ActionBase;
        var foobar1:ActionBase = new ActionBase();
        actionQueue[actionQueue.length] = foobar1;
        actionQueue[actionQueue.length] = new ActionBase();
        actionQueue[actionQueue.length] = Object;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < actionQueue.length; ++i)
        {
            action = actionQueue[i] as ActionBase;
            if (action != null && action is ActionBase)
            {
                action.step();

                if (action.done())
                {
                    trace("all done");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
}

class ActionBase {
    var _done:Boolean = false;
    function ActionBase() {
    }
    function done():Boolean {
        trace(done);
        return _done;
    }
    function step() {
        _done = true;
        trace(step);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added more info to my original post.  Thanks for your test code - it looks pretty close to what I'm doing.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @kitfox hmmm...can you update your answer and post the actual line of code in that the compiler error is occurring on

Answer (score 0):

Is your object a movieclip?

Did you try setting ActionBase as base class for your objects?

Or trying casting like this:

`ActionBase(Arr[i]).step()`

Or just try without casting.